# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have this data:

new.csv:

```
X         Y
230.1   22.1
44.5    10.4
17.2    9.3
151.5   18.5
180.8   12.9
8.7 7.2
57.5    11.8
120.2   13.2
8.6 4.8
199.8   10.6
66.1    8.6
214.7   17.4
23.8    9.2
97.5    9.7
204.1   19
195.4   22.4
67.8    12.5
281.4   24.4
69.2    11.3
```

and I am trying to apply linear regression model.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model, cross_validation
import random 

data = pd.read_csv('./data/new.csv', names=['X', 'Y'], header=0)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

x = data.loc[:,'X'].to_frame()
y = data.loc[:,'Y'].to_frame()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

regr.fit(x_train, y_train)


ax.set(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', title='X vs Y')
ax.scatter(x_test,y_test, alpha=0.5, cmap='viridis')
ax.plot(x_test, regr.predict(x_test), color='red', linewidth=2)
```

Until here, everything runs fine. The moment I try to add an errorbar:

```
plt.errorbar(x_test,y_test, yerr=1, fmt='o');
```

I am receiving the error in the title.

The full error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-cf35bd0c650f> in <module>()
     29 
     30 #dy=1
---> 31 plt.errorbar(x_test,y_test, yerr=1);

../anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in errorbar(x, y, yerr, xerr, fmt, ecolor, elinewidth, capsize, barsabove, lolims, uplims, xlolims, xuplims, errorevery, capthick, hold, data, **kwargs)
   2835                           xlolims=xlolims, xuplims=xuplims,
   2836                           errorevery=errorevery, capthick=capthick, data=data,
-> 2837                           **kwargs)
   2838     finally:
   2839         ax.hold(washold)

../anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1817                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1818                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1819             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1820         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1821         if pre_doc is None:

../anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in errorbar(self, x, y, yerr, xerr, fmt, ecolor, elinewidth, capsize, barsabove, lolims, uplims, xlolims, xuplims, errorevery, capthick, **kwargs)
   2924 
   2925         if yerr is not None:
-> 2926             lower, upper = extract_err(yerr, y)
   2927             # select points without upper/lower limits in y and
   2928             # draw normal errorbars for these points

../anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in extract_err(err, data)
   2873             # using list comps rather than arrays to preserve units
   2874             low = [thisx - thiserr for (thisx, thiserr)
-> 2875                    in cbook.safezip(data, err)]
   2876             high = [thisx + thiserr for (thisx, thiserr)
   2877                     in cbook.safezip(data, err)]

../anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   2872                                      "dimensions as x, or 2xN.")
   2873             # using list comps rather than arrays to preserve units
-> 2874             low = [thisx - thiserr for (thisx, thiserr)
   2875                    in cbook.safezip(data, err)]
   2876             high = [thisx + thiserr for (thisx, thiserr)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the entire traceback. It helps debug the issue.

Comment: For me it works perfect. But it seems some your data are not numeric, test it with `df.dtypes`. Then try cast to `float` like `df['X'] = df['X'].astype(float)` and if value error `df['X'] = pd.to_numeric(df['X'], errors='coerce')` for convert not numeric values to `NaN`

Comment: @jezrael:I am using the X and Y values as the above.They are all numeric.(tested also and returns float64)

Comment: @jezrael:I can' understand why it worked for you.I am using the exact above numbers and it only works if I use x_test.values

Comment: I think about it. Maybe bug, maybe I use python 3 in win with `pandas: 0.19.1` ,`matplotlib: 1.5.1`, `scipy: 0.17.0` and `numpy: 1.11.0`. So maybe help upgrade.

Comment: @jezrael:I upgraded panda but still the same.Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried:

```
plt.errorbar(x_test.values, y_test.values, yerr=1, fmt='o');
```

and it worked!